# Disable SSLv3 in IPSec CentosOS

Tags: openssl, ipsec, centos

I have been told to shut down support to SSLV3 - TLS 1.0 - TLS 1.1 to all encrypted communications towards external web services.

Now, I have an IPSec/CentOS gateway in front of my Data Center.How can I check which protocol it's using? And, how can I disable SSLv3 and TLS < 1.2 from the tunnels created between my gateway nad external networks?
Or rather, how can I guarantee that IPSec is "safe" against SSLV3?

Comment: IPSec does not use SSL/TLS.

Comment: see the edited question, because I have been told to check also IPSec

Comment: "how can I guarantee that IPSec is "safe" against SSLV3?" - please clarify that line. I am failing to understand why IPSec would need to be "safe agast SSLV3" and I am unsure what that actually means or how you would even achieve that. They're pretty unrelated things.

Comment: @giuseppe: again, IPSec does not use SSL/TLS at all and your edit does not change this fact. Whoever told you to check IPSec for SSLv3 either had not enough knowledge of IPSec or you've misunderstood your task.